# Truncate integer using bit twiddling

Tags: algorithm, math, integer, bit-manipulation

Is there a way to "truncate" an integer using bit twiddling, as if it floor-divided and then multiplied back, as in:

```
z = floor(x / y) * y
```

I know it is possible to do so if `y` is of power of two, for example:

```
z = floor(x / 4) * 4 == x & ~3
```

But what trick does one use when `y` is some general positive integer?

Comment: If think that if there was a way to do it in the general case, then it would make the running-time complexity of division equivalent to that of addition and subtraction (which, to the best of my knowledge, is not the case for arbitrary size input).

Comment: No, there isn't a way

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `z = x - (x%y)` (only works for unsigned values/types)

Comment: For each individual `y`, there is a sequence of operations (addition, subtraction, and binary shift) which divides `x` by `y` faster than the (x86) division instruction. Finding that sequence however is not straightforward, and must be done in advance (feasible when you divide by the same `y` **a lot**). See Hacker's Delight book in general, and the freely available addition - chapter 10 here: http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf.

Comment: @wildplasser: There is no "bit twiddling" in using the modulo operation.

Comment: That is correct. But it reduces div+mult to mod+sub, which *could* be cheaper.

Comment: @Gassa Post your comment below, I will accept it as the answer. Thanks, that's the closest thing to what I was looking for.

Comment: @EcirHana Done, elaborated a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each individual `y`, there is a sequence of operations (addition, subtraction, and binary shift) which divides `x` by `y` faster than the (x86) division instruction.
Finding that sequence however is not straightforward, and must be done in advance (feasible when you divide by the same `y` **a lot**).

A simple example: to divide an arbitrary `uint32` `x` by 3, we can instead calculate `x * M` in `uint64` type and shift it to the right by 33 bits, where `M` is a magic constant equal to 2<sup>33</sup> / 3 rounded **up**.

The following code (C) tries 20 random `uint32` values with the above algorithm and checks that the result is equal to just dividing by 3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    int step;
    unsigned x, y1, y2;
    unsigned const M = (1ULL << 33) / 3 + 1;
    srand (time (NULL));
    for (step = 0; step < 20; step++)
    {
        x = (rand () << 30) | (rand () << 15) | rand ();
        y1 = x / 3;
        y2 = (x * 1ULL * M) >> 33;
        printf ("%10u %10u %10u %s\n", x, y1, y2, y1 == y2 ? "true" : "false");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For further information, see Hacker's Delight book in general, and the freely available addition - chapter 10 here: [hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf](http://hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The reason this works for powers of 2 is the way binary representations works. Dividing by 2 (or powers of 2) is identical to bit shifting. Shifting right and then back left the same amount is identical to floor-division as you put it.

Consider an arbitrary binary number: 110101010111. If you'd bit shift it 3 times to the right (division by 8), and then back again it would turn to 110101010000 which is identical to ANDing it with 111111111000. Now lets consider division by 3 of the (decimal) number 16: start with 10000. Division (not shifting!) by 3 would be 5 (101) and multiply by 3 again is 15 (1111). No bit shifting can do that.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing to do is to convert to whatever base you are trying to work with, and then basically make the last digit 0. (Or if you are working with a kth power, then make the last k digits 0). However you asked about bit (base-2) operations. It turns out that for any desired base B (at least, that is odd), you can come up with a number in binary so that the first M digits in base B are anything you want, for any M. Thus, how could you possibly have a general method for what you want (with an odd base), that just works on bits (binary)? At the very least it would probably be a lot more complicated than simply converting your number to your desired base and setting however many last digits to 0 and then converting back to natural base-2 integer representation.